# Is there a way to make an object for PHPUnit return NULL on creation?

Tags: php, interface, phpunit

I am trying to create a test for PHPUnit, however - in the class we are testing, there is a situation where the passed object is checked to be `NULL`.

I have created the object like so (actually an interface):

```
class SomeTestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase {

    protected $storage;

    public function setUp() {
      $this->storage = $this->getMockBuilder('Some\Namespace\TestedInterface')->getMock();
    }

    public function testStorage() {

      /* here is where I need to pass over $this->storage to testFunc() and assert it is null */ 

      $testingClass = new TestingClass();
      $testingClass->testFunc( $this->storage );

    }
  }
```

So - what I need to do is create an object that is a mock of an interface, whose 'return' value is `null` when it is checked in the `testFunc()` function.

How do I do that? Our `TestingClass` class expects an object that implements an interface.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to test what happens when you pass a `null` to `testFunc()`? Why not simply pass `null` then? If your framework always expects an actual object, well, you obviously cannot test that, but why would you want to test an impossible case anyway?

Comment: No, I can test that - I just need to make sure that the object passed over is an implementation of an interface whose return value is null

Comment: What do you mean by 'return value' of an interface? Do you mean you want some kind of special `null` value which is of a certain type/interface?

Comment: Its not a return value of the interface, but the class that implements said interface. It may be a flaw in the class i am testing in all honesty, because if the object is null, then it will bomb out before it even gets to test if the object is null. It would blow up in the constructor

Comment: Ok, so you know that passing `null` to `testFunc()` will result in an error/exception/crash/whatever. I guess you want to 'fix' this behavior, or at least, test for this. What exactly prevents you from passing `null` to `testFunc()`, e.g., `$testingClass->testFunc(null);`? (Maybe I don't understand the problem, but your description is really confusing so far)